# Multiple foreign keys from a TPH in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two three models: Reservation, Buyer and SalesAgent. What my app does is, a reservation can be placed with a Buyer and at the same time, a SalesAgent. Here is my structure for my models:

**Reservation**

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Reservation Date.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Reservation Date")]
    public string ReservationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual HouseUnit HouseUnit { get; set; }
    public int HouseUnitID { get; set; }

    public virtual Buyer Buyer { get; set; }
    public int BuyerID { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesAgent SalesAgent { get; set; }
    public int SalesAgentID { get; set; }

}
```

**Buyer**

```
public class Buyer
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter enter birth date.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Current Address")]
    [Required]
    public string CurrentAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Occupation { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Monthly Income")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
    public double MonthlyIncome { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Company { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your must provide a contact number.")]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Number")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(\d{11})$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter proper contact details.")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    public bool HasPlacedReservation { get; set; }
}
```

**SalesAgent**

```
public class SalesAgent : Buyer {}
```

The problem comes when running `Update-Database`. Here's the error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Reservations_dbo.BuyersInformations_SalesAgentID' on table 'Reservations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Can somebody please explain what happens and how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: will you share the `BuyersInformation ` class.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you have a situation where Object A has a reference to Object B, which has a reference to Object A, which has a reference to Object B, which ... ad infinitum. This isn't bad practice, per se, but Entity Framework cannot handle this situation because Object A and Object B depend on one another; if you delete one, the other gets deleted in a chain-reaction type of effect (aka cascade), which can cause other dependent objects to be deleted in the reaction. Entity Framework is asking you to solve this situation by either eliminating one object's dependency on another, or to instruct it to not cascade delete these objects that have foreign key constraints with one another. If you'd prefer to not do the first option, you must tell Entity Framework to not cascade delete these objects. You can perform this globally with your DbContext object with the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    // ...
}
```

This will instruct all one-to-many relationships to not perform a cascading delete. You can also individually instruct Entity Framework to not cascade delete on specific items using the following Fluent API code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.ObjectB)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    // ...
}
```

Above is merely an example. Your exact Fluent API code will differ from the above depending on if the dependencies are optional or not, or if they are one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many.

That said, while the above code may solve your problem, in the long-run this may be more of a band-aid solution. There may be a bigger issue with your objects and their dependencies that is worth investigating further.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to answer this issue. I tried your first solution, but it did not work. How do I link two foreign keys to a table?

Comment: Using Fluent API, the following code will map a many-to-many relationship to its own separate table: `modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectA>().HasMany(a => a.ObjectBList).WithMany().Map(m => { m.ToTable("YourNewTableName"); m.MapLeftKey("ObjectAID"); m.MapRightKey("ObjectBID"); });`